# Wildfly service 10.0 and 10.1 cannot be stopped in Windows

Tags: java, jboss, windows-services, wildfly, wildfly-10

We have successfully installed both Wildfly 10.0 and Wildfly 10.1 in Windows system (Windows 10 and Windows server  2008/2012) as a service but when we try to stop it this operation fails.
If we try to stop it from Windows Service Manager we get error 1053, instead if I launch  `service.bat stop` from  `<WILDFLY_ROOT>\bin\service` I get the error "Failed to load service service_name configuration". In both cases service remains forever in "Stopping" state in Windows services manager.

I now there are some documented issues like [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3149) but I have already done many trials. 
In my `service.bat` for Wildfly 10 I have set both `JBOSSUSER` and `JBOSSPASS` variables to be used in shutdown command and I set them both with the ones used for Wildfly management console (I know that not setting up management console will prevent Wildfly from being stopped) and with a real Windows ones (my login account in Windows). I know they are correctly used as CREDENTIALS for shutdown when running .bat file.
That does not work.
Moreover, I thought the problem was caused as we have both JDK 6 and JDK 8 installed. JDK 8 is to run Widlfly while JDK 6 is still (unfortunately) used to develop our software. I set JAVA_HOME variable in jboss-cli.bat file to JDK 8 but that does not work too. For sure, `java -version` command prints 1.8.0_171 and `echo %JAVA_HOME%` commands prints path to `jdk1.8.0_144`
How can I solve this?